# Gases have no fixed volume does that mean that one mole of any gas can occupy whole universe?

Tags: gas-laws

First of all , how can one prove that gases have no fixed volume ? And if (though i know that it have) lets take a case . Take small amount of gas and fill it into a large box , about size of earth , consider that box has vacuum in it . The gas should fill all the earth but if does that  , then the intermolecular attraction force should be inconsiderable or negligible at such large distances . What happen then ? There should be a limit to the volume ...

Another question is why molecule let H2 not attract another gas particle let He as there is same van der Waals force ........

Comment: Even vacuum can occupy the whole universe...

Comment: Of course this isn't entirely true. The "normal" gas laws neglect gravity. Fortunately for us a sufficiently large amount of hydrogen gas in outer space can collapse into a star.

Answer (score 0):

Gases have no fixed volume, if you put it in an infinite vacuum, a gas will at equilibrium have an infinite volume. You'll be waiting a while for it to reach equilibrium though.
H2 will have some interaction with He, but it's very weak, so for most purposes can be neglected.

Comment: Why b/w he and h2 is weak force  there but not b/w h2 and h2

Comment: @dr.honey Yes there is also an attractive force between individual H2 molecules.

Comment: Ya i know .....i want to know why only He-He has attraction but not in  H2-He?

Comment: @dr.honey All gas molecules interact, but He-He interaction is weakest known. See comments [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/21822/9961)