# Which elements can be diatomic?

Tags: bond, atoms, elements

Which elements can be diatomic and why?

---

**Motivation**

Hydrogen, Nitrogen, Oxygen and the Halogens tend to be thermodynamically stable as a diatomic molecule at room temperature, and are usually labelled as diatomic nonmetals. (Although I am unsure about Astatine). These are the ones you learn in school and I am fine with their reasoning. I want to know about other elements in particular.

Looking at the rest of the non-metals: [Carbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomic_carbon), [Phosphorus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphosphorus) and [Sulfur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disulfur) have diatomic molecules in gaseous states. All with a common theme of being heated at very high temperatures.

This leaves us with diatomic Selenium which I could not find anything on.

---

**Further notes**

Diatomicity doesn't seem to be just a non-metal thing:

- Lithium forms diatomic molecules and [all diatomic alkali metals are claimed to be stable in gaseous states](http://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/principles-of-general-chemistry-v1.0/s13-molecular-geometry-and-covalen.html#averill_1.0-ch09_s03_s02_f02). Found from [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32686/is-it-possible-to-have-a-diatomic-molecule-of-sodium-in-gaseous-state).
- Silicon [has been reported](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cen-v086n034.p010) to have a diatomic molecule similar in structure to carbon.
- Tungsten, Chromium, Uranium and Molybdenum are [claimed to be diatomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextuple_bond) with a sextuple bond.
- Supposedly [Noble gases can form dimer molecules](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/518/do-noble-gasses-besides-helium-form-diatomic-molecules-at-low-temperatures) but if these are considered diatomic is debatable.

Comment: I have a feeling almost every element can be found as a diatomic molecule in the right conditions (or at least present as a measurable mole fraction), though high temperatures and low pressures may be needed for many of them. In the majority of cases, *any* chemical bond will be more stable than *no* chemical bond. Plus there are some stranger cases, such as bound diatomic noble gas molecules, stable when encapsulated by a fullerene molecule.

Comment: Alkali-earth metals and noble gases definitely can't form stable diatomic molecules, Zn/Cd/Hg likely can't too.  Homoatomic bonds for most heavy non-transition metals are very weak so detecting diatomic molecules is unlikely.

Comment: @permeakra Look at the bottom of further notes for noble gases.

Comment: @permeakra Diberyllium [exists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_diagram): 'diberyllium molecule exists (and has been observed in the gas phase). It nevertheless still has a low dissociation energy of only $59~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}}$.' Also see [here](http://chem.vander-lingen.nl/articles/Diberyllium/id/126/itemid/446).

Comment: @bon Interesting, it shouldn't. Well, Palladium clasters shouldn't exist to, but they do.

Comment: Depends what you call diatomic - if you count helium vdV dimer than two atoms of any element which will have occasion and time will get bound.

Comment: "Stable" is a somewhat nebulous property. In general a chemist would think of stable to mean that the molecule would survive some large ( how big is large??) number of intermolecular collisions.   In the cold of deep space where collisions are infrequent I'm sure that any two atoms would form a "molecule." If you increased the partial pressure so that such "molecules" started colliding, then the list would be different.

Comment: I think sodium in the gas phase exists as a dimer, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> This leaves us with diatomic Selenium which I could not find anything on.

Selenium forms a dimer with bond energy of 79 kcal/mol, according to table 8.6 (page 451) of [Comprehensive Handbook of Chemical Bond Energies](https://books.google.com/books?id=kM3mwD4y_TAC&pg=PA1652&lpg=PA1652&dq=selenium%20dimer&source=bl&ots=2Pk9euhll4&sig=GUJl2Mq5eYx7nos6tDLDlHEmjIM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFgQ6AEwCGoVChMI7veuiJPjyAIVRFcmCh0jqgIB#v=onepage&q=selenium%20dimer&f=false), which provides 5 references.

Tellenium dimer is 61 kcal/mol

Polonium dimer 45 kcal/mol