Molecules of the alkali metal group
Does $\ce{Na2}$ and $\ce{K2}$ exist according to MOT? My professor said they do but then why don't we observe them?

And what "why don't we observe them?" is supposed to mean? They're perfectly fine in vapor phase.

Before why, ask if, the best by searching in available offline and online sources. The only metal in gaseous phase, known for not forming molecules at least in traces, is mercury. Forming molecules is more prominent at high temperatures with high enough vapor pressure.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/which-elements-can-be-diatomic

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32686/is-it-possible-to-have-a-diatomic-molecule-of-sodium-in-gaseous-state
